# Как программно выбрать ползунок resize?

Tags: javascript, css

Нужно при зажатии мыши в зеленой области расширять или сужать левый блок,я решил это реализовать с помощью resize свойства,которое делает блок расширяемым с помощью ползунка(как у textarea).Но проблема в том,что тогда блок расширяется только при зажатии только этого ползунка снизу,поэтому я решил,что нужно отслеживать зажатие мыши в зеленой области и одновременно с ним выделять и этот ползунок,но я не знаю как это сделать
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я так понимаю "этот" это "самописный" вариант?

Comment: @De.Minov нет,я просто добавил диву css свойство resize:horizontal

Comment: Тогда не совсем понятно о чём речь.

Comment: @De.Minov Обновил вопрос,может станет понятнее

Comment: @IvanSmirnoff? нет, такой финт не пройдёт. Нужно делать блок-ресайзер, на нём отслеживать события, и уже на основе событий производить манипуляции.

Comment: @UModeL ладно,спасибо за ответы,посмотрю еще как это сделать

Comment: Создайте абсолютную зону под объектом и на следуйте поведение курсора

Answer (score 0):

Ты можешь использовать для этого css

```
::-webkit-resizer {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px blue;
  outline: 2px solid yellow;
}
```

Comment: спасибо,но мне нужно выбрать его с помощью js

Comment: @IvanSmirnoff, тогда укажите в вопросе конечную цель - что Вы собираетесь делать при выборе уголка. Может быть, что "не нужно забивать микроскопом гвозди, если есть молоток".

Comment: @UModeL Обновил вопрос,может станет понятнее

Answer (score -2):

> блок расширяется только при зажатии только этого ползунка снизу

т.е. само действие полностью устраивает, но нужно чтоб оно срабатывало при драге любой части границы блоков, верно?

```html
<div id='conteiner'>
  <div id='ch1'>1</div>
  <div onMouseDown='lisenMouse();'>resizer</div>
  <div id='ch2'>2</div>
</div>
```

где lisenMouse() - слушалка координат мыши, как раз такая как надо тут(на этом сайте) к нижней границе тектового поля прилеплена.
с одним небольшим но, эта слушает вертикальную ось, тебе же нужна горизонтальная.

p.s. не силён в координации мыши, так что готового примера у меня нет.

// если никто раньше не подскажет, погугли какой нибудь js - dragNdrop скрипт например.